# When to replace a global std::unique_ptr with a singleton

Tags: c++

A colleague has insisted on using Meyer's Singleton for all global pointer variables as "there's no guarantee the construction of the global `unique_ptr` won't throw". So instead of:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(nullptr); // Apparently this isn't safe.

int main(/*blah*/)
{
    ptr.reset(new Foo());
}
```

We now have

```
unique_ptr<Foo> singleton
{ 
    try 
    { 
        static unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(); 
        return ptr; 
    } 
    catch (...) 
    { 
        std::cerr << "Failed to create single instance\n"; 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    return unique_ptr<Type>(); 
}

int main()
{
}
```

To me this seems like a solution looking for a problem. Does he have a point?

Comment: Also, I would argue that catching the exception, and then doing an exit (and throwing away any chance of figuring out why it failed), seems like a worse idea.  Most systems, an unhandled exception terminates AND produces debugging output (such as a core file).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your colleague is incorrect (or perhaps just out of date, pre-standard versions of `unique_ptr` might be different). The `nullptr_t` constructor of `unique_ptr` is guaranteed not to throw (20.7.1.2):

```
constexpr unique_ptr (nullptr_t) noexcept : unique_ptr() {}
```

Since it's also `constexpr` (and since `nullptr` is a constant expression), it is required to be initialized during constant initialization (3.6.2/2). So controlling initialization order (the other reason the Meyers singleton might be useful) also doesn't apply here.

Comment: All `unique_ptr` ctors are noexcept. `constexpr` ctor allows initialization during _constant initialization_, part of _static initialization_, which is performed before *any* _dynamic initialization_.

Comment: @DyP: merely allows, or requires?

Comment: Allows, there are further requirements for the init to be performed during _constant initialization_, see [basic.start.init]/2

Comment: Is this the case for `shared_ptr` also?

Comment: @James: the `nullptr_t` constructor of `shared_ptr` is not marked `noexcept`, but the no-args constructor is. Which is a bit odd, since the former is defined to just call the latter, so I think that in fact it cannot throw. The constructors of `shared_ptr` that take an actual pointer to managed data can throw.

Answer (score 2):

> "there's no guarantee the construction of the global unique_ptr won't throw"

And if it throws, what happens?  The application gets terminated, although the Standard doesn't specify if the stack gets unwound if you don't catch the exception (as a global variable, there's no place to catch the exception).  I'm not clear how the proposed solution is a clear improvement over that.